# laravel join query with two table each have two where condition

Tags: php, laravel

this is my controller and i need to add one where condition on table chapters with is_enabled = 0

```
 $module = $course->modules()
                    ->with('chapters')
                    ->join('course_student', 'course_student.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')
                    ->select('*', DB::raw('course_student.module_id as id'))
                    ->where('is_enabled', 1)
                    ->where('course_student.student_id', $user->id)
                    ->where('course_student.test_completed', 0)
                    ->where('course_student.ends_on', '>', Carbon::now())
                    ->orderBy('order')
                    ->first();
```

Comment: S.O. is not a code completion service. Please show what have you tried so far and the errors you are receiving for that.

Comment: how to in clude a where condition in chapters table

Comment: You simply do  ->where('chapters.chapter_name', $chapterName)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `whereHas` method if you want conditional selection of relationships.

> These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a
>   relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment

[Relationships documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Leaving you with a code like:

```
$module = $course->modules()
    ->whereHas('chapters', function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_enabled', 0);
    })
    ->join('course_student', 'course_student.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('course_student.module_id as id'))
    ->where('is_enabled', 1)
    ->where('course_student.student_id', $user->id)
    ->where('course_student.test_completed', 0)
    ->where('course_student.ends_on', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->orderBy('order')
    ->first();
```